# Remove all but one word in a line - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking for a way to search for a specific string e.g. '@' and delete everything before and after that string. I would prefer a way/macro/addon for Notepad++ but anything would be helpful.

Here is the line now (Note that the numbers are always different per line so you couldn't do a search and replace with them):

```
Follow Follow @BararRohit User actions Rohit Barar @BararRohit
```

I want to be able to remove everything in the following line except one portion so that the end result looks like this:

`@BararRohit`

Comment: Welcome to to SuperUser.  I advise editing the question in the following ways : Use better title with capitalization like "Remove Starting Characters on a line".  Make it easy for the eye to see before / after.  Perhaps capitalize BEFORE and AFTER , and put the line starting "Note" in your first paragraph.

Comment: Regex is a good tool for this, which is available in the NotePad++ Search/Replace box after you've learned how to use it. I suggest visiting some training sites like https://regexr.com/ or https://regexone.com/ .  If your source text comes from Mac or Linux, beware of the different line endings.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for your example but you could [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1378869/edit) to show other examples.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*(@\w+).*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*          # 0 or more any character
(           # start group 1
    @       # literally @
    \w+     # 1 or more word character (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
)           # end group 1
.*          # 0 or more any character
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1  # content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
@BararRohit
```